# M-Lab Table Access from BigQuery Not Working

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to access the M-Lab tables from BigQuery but keep getting this message:

Error: Access Denied: Table measurement-lab:m_lab.2010_01: QUERY_TABLE

I can access the other sample tables just fine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Access to the M-lab tables requires you to be on the M-lab project as at least a 'reader'. Do you know if you've been added? I will contact the M-lab folks at Google to see if they're willing to add all users to the acl, which means that anyone will be able to access.

Comment: I haven't requested to be added so I'm probably not set up.  If we could get set up that would be great!